# How to add contacts from ruby to Gmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-contacts-api

I want to add contacts from my rails application to Gmail account. Is there any gem available to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: I use [mail_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) as my contact form in my app.

Comment: I have a prebuild application that contains a lot of contacts. Now there is a requirement to import contacts to gmail so that all the contacts can be accessed by an organisation.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Your question is off-topic because you're asking us for recommendations for software. Instead you should research, then try things, then start writing code, and _then_ ask a question when you run into a problem with your code. Or, ask on [softwarerecs.se], where it'd be more on-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this gem to [Gemfile](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/people/v1)

> gem 'google-api-client', '0.9.3', require: ['google/apis/people_v1']